# Extract data with double quotes and header without quotes from SQL table using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to extract data from SQL Server table with headers excluding double quotes) and the rest of the data with double-quotes. I have to further load this data into CSV. The data or header doesn't have any quoting in SQL table

The expected format for the CSV should be:

ID,Name,Salary

"1","ABC","111"

I tried using:
`df = df.to_csv(filename, index= None, header=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)`
but it gives me entire data with headers without double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.to_csv(filename, index= None, header=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

or

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(str)
df['Name'] = df['Name'].astype(str)
df['Salary'] = df['Salary'].astype(str)
df.to_csv(filename, index= None, header=True)
```

should do

Comment: I looped through the columns with astype(str) then converted it to csv using 'df.to_csv(filename, index= None, header=True)'
There were no double quotes at all. I need double quotes only in data and not in header